# optimize.root() does not find solution to a smooth function

Tags: python, scipy, solver

I hope that my question can be answered without having runnable code, as its too complex to create a small but running version. The following code is part of my project:

```
x0 = [0.5, 0.5]
solution = optimize.root(solveMe, x0, args=(Param, Result, False), method='broyden1')
if solution.status != 1:
    Result.__dict__
    two.plot_some_function(solveMe, np.arange(0.1, 1.5, 0.1), np.arange(0.1, 1.5, 0.1), Param, Result, False)
    raise Exception ('did not converge')
```

`solveMe` is a function that returns a vector of two residuals, `F(x0)`. Whenever `root()` does not converge, I create a grid between `0.1` and `1.5` for both variables and just plot the output of `F(x0)` for any `xo` on that two-dimensional grid. I also check whether there are grid points such that *both* residuals are close to zero. The code follows:

```
# for debuggign
def plot_some_function(func, x, y, *args):

    from matplotlib import cm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z0 = np.empty(X.shape)
    Z1 = np.empty(X.shape)

    for idx in np.ndindex(X.shape):
        x, y = X[idx], Y[idx]
        Z0[idx], Z1[idx] = func([x,y], *args)
        if (abs(Z0[idx]) < 0.1) & (abs(Z1[idx]) < 0.1):
            print idx

    for Z in [Z0, Z1]:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        p = ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.RdBu, vmin=abs(Z).min(), vmax=abs(Z).max())
        cb = fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)
    plt.show()
```

I ran my main code. I got an exception, the solution does not converge with a set of parameters. Following are the plots (which show that the function is actually quite smooth).

[image: residual: first equation in F]
[image: residual: second equation in F]

The idx output was

```
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
```

which corresponds to `(0.2, 0.1)` and `(0.3, 0.2)`.

But why does `root()` not converge then? Its output follows

```
  status: 2
 success: False
     fun: array([ 0.01725503,  0.25234002])
       x: array([ 0.36981866,  0.4440247 ])
 message: 'The maximum number of iterations allowed has been reached.'
     nit: 300
```

An additional fine-tuning in the grid for the matrices actually gives me the coordinates for the following:

```
solveMe([0.165, 0.258], Param, Result, False)
Out[6]: array([ 0.00012388,  0.00105457])
```

Which is much smaller than what the solver found.

Comment: Are you sure there is a solution where `solveMe(x)` is (0.0, 0.0)?  From your plots, it doesn't appear that way, but it is hard to tell--the grid is rather coarse.  It looks like the values of both components are always positive.

Comment: Yeah the plots are weird, I think one of them gets mirrored (or something like that happens with the axis). That's why I added the code that checks for points where *both* are close to 0.0

Comment: I'm still not sure if you know if there is--at least theoretically--a point where solveMe(x) should be *exactly* (0 ,0).  How much do you really know about this function?  If you consider `solveMe(x) = (1e-4, 1e-3)` close enough to (0,0) to be considered a root, you should increase `tol`, or set the tolerance options for the specific solver that you are using ("broyden1", in this case).  But there might be a large region where this condition holds.  In that case, is the solution `x` actually useful?

Comment: I'm positive that it has at least one root. I couldn't show uniqueness of that yet, though. And the point with '1e-f' is just that I showed that there is at least one point (that I found with very crude grid search) that is "better" than what the solver found.

Comment: Root finders are only as good as their initial guess.  Since the return message is that the number of iterations has been reached, that means you were not particularly close to a solution, or that the function is pathological in that general area. I'd take a close look at the function - your plots above have a z-range of zero to 3.6 million, and your function is returning values less than 1. If the function is so complex you can't provide it, the behavior near the roots (if they exist) may be really complex as well.